# Definition of stochastic integral on an interval

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X$ be a semimartingale und $H$ a predictable locally bounded process. For me $\int_0^t H_s dX_s$ was always just a notation for $(H \cdot X)_t$ and $H \cdot X$ is properly defined. On page 60 in the book Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations from Protter he writes

$$ (H \cdot X)_t=\int_0^t H_s dX_s=\int_{[0,t]} H_s dX_s$$

and defines

$$\int_{0+}^t H_s dX_s=\int_{(0,t]} H_s dX_s.$$

I don't understand the meaning of this. Can one define the stochastic integral on intervals?

Comment: It's defined in the same way as it would be for the Lebesgue integral, $$\int_{0+}^t H_s dX_s=\int_{(0,t]} H_s dX_s = \int_{\left[0,t\right]} \mathbf{1}_{\left(0,t\right]}\left(s\right)  H_s dX_s, $$ where $ \mathbf{1}_{\left(0,t\right]}\left(s\right)$ is the indicator of the set $\left(0,t\right]$. There is no problem with defining the stochastic integral as $ s\mapsto \mathbf{1}_{\left(0,t\right]}\left(s\right)$ is left continuous.